# Can I hide JavaScript code with Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, mqtt, google-cloud-functions

I have a JavaScript web page that sends MQTT data to a server running Mosquitto. I want to hide the MQTT server name, username and password  from the user. I know it isn't possible with plain JavaScript because the sources are visible in the console.

Is it possible to do it with Firebase cloud functions? And if yes how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is in fact one of the key capabilities mentioned in the [Cloud Functions for Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/#key_capabilities):

> **Keeps your logic private and secure**
>
> In many cases, developers prefer to control application logic on the server to avoid tampering on the client side. Also, sometimes it's not desirable to allow that code to be reverse engineered. Cloud Functions is fully insulated from the client, so you can be sure it is private and always does exactly what you want

There are quite some samples in Firebase's [functions-samples repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples).

For example, the sample that sends email confirmation to users requires the gmail credentials for sending emails. You'll never want to embed those credentials in the application code, where a malicious user is likely to find them and abuse them. So this code is a great candidate to run in Cloud Functions. The [code that reads these values](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/email-confirmation/functions/index.js#L20-L26) from this sample:

> ```
> // Configure the email transport using the default SMTP transport and a GMail account.
> // For other types of transports such as Sendgrid see https://nodemailer.com/transports/
> // TODO: Configure the `gmail.email` and `gmail.password` Google Cloud environment variables.
> const gmailEmail = encodeURIComponent(functions.config().gmail.email);
> const gmailPassword = encodeURIComponent(functions.config().gmail.password);
> const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(
>     `smtps://${gmailEmail}:${gmailPassword}@smtp.gmail.com`);
> ```

You could hard-code the email address and password, since only developers on your project will be able to see it. But in this case the sample does it even better and keeps the credentials in server-side configuration that it reads with `functions.config()`. To learn how to set these, read the [documentation for the sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/email-confirmation#setting-up-the-sample):

> Set the `gmail.email` and `gmail.password` Google Cloud environment variables to match the email and password of the Gmail account used to send emails (or the app password if your account has 2-step verification enabled). For this use:
>
> ```
> firebase functions:config:set gmail.email="myusername@gmail.com" gmail.password="secretpassword"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think even API keys can be stored securely over firebase functions. I have put down my thoughts in [an article](https://medium.com/@mayurdube/can-cloud-functions-for-firebase-be-the-secure-way-to-hide-api-keys-for-mobile-apps-508feb4d00f7) and a [Github repo](https://github.com/mdrepo/firebase-functions) for a detailed approach to save firebase config variables and access them. Have a look.